# Putting constant and final in Dart

Tags: dart

I was going through the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and noticed that they have the statement

```dart
final constantSet = const {
  'fluorine'
};
```

and I was just wondering whether there is a programmatic difference in declaring the constant as final or whether that has a specific purpose. I can see that we can place `const` either before or after the variable declaration, is this the same thing, considering that when you declare a variable as final it is only able to be initialized once anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference.

A `final constantSet = const {'fluorine'};` declares a non-constant final variable bound to a value which happens to be a compile-time constant.

A `const constantSet = const {'fluorine'};` declares a constant variable bound to a compile-time constant value (and the second `const` can be omitted).

The latter allows you to use `constantSet` in constant expressions, so `const [costantSet]` is only valid with the latter declaration.
That also means that declaring a variable as `const` is something you cannot take back. Changing a `const` declaration to `final` may break code using the `const` variable in constant expression. That's a reason for not making every variable const, just because it *can* be. You might not want to promise that it stays constant forever.